# How to find out if some eigenvalues of a matrix are the same?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that in order for a matrix to have two equal eigenvalues, one term in the characteristic polynomial must be in the power of two. Is there any way to tell if two eigenvalues are the same? I have seen many algorithms wich are based on the assumption that eigenvalues are not the same, does this have to be checked?

Comment: Obviously if the characteristic polynomial has a factor of the form $(x-a)^n$.

Comment: I know, but I want to find that out without calculating the characteristic polynomial.I want to know if there are any algorithms.  @shahab

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial $f$ has a multiple root iff $\gcd(f,f')\ne 1$.